# Конструктор динамических имён методов

Tags: ruby, метапрограммирование

У меня есть несколько методов с однотипными префиксами.

```
def get_foo
  # code
end

def get_bar
  # code
end
```

Я хочу научиться генерировать эти префиксы автоматически (по аналогии с тем, как это сделано в Rails: `Model.find_by_smth`).

Т.е. я хочу создать некий scope `get_`, в который можно поместить метод `foo` и тот автоматически приобретёт префикс `get_` и станет доступен как `get_foo`.

Как это можно реализовать?

---

Пример желаемого синтаксиса.

```
module Bar
  # некая обётка `get_`
end

class Foo
  include Bar

  <некая обёртка из Bar> do
    def foo
      puts 'У меня есть мысль, и я её думаю!'
    end

    def bar
      puts 'А можно я её тоже немножечко подумаю?'
    end
  end
end

foo = Foo.new

foo.get_foo # => "У меня есть мысль, и я её думаю!"
foo.get_bar # => "А можно я её тоже немножечко подумаю?"
```

Comment: Приведите пример синтаксиса, который хотели бы видеть.

Comment: Эм-м, вы, наверное, хотели определить в `Bar` только обёртку, а сами методы в `Foo` (с использованием обёртки из модуля)? Потому что в текущей затее я не вижу большого смысла. Точнее говоря, я не вижу смысла в отдельном модуле, если уж делать минимальный пример :)

Comment: @D-side Естественно, в реальном коде все намного сложнее :)
И префиксов будет несколько. Просто есть вариант сделать в качестве обёртки модуль, но я интересовался, можно ли сделать методы с динамическими именами

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Module
  def with_prefix(prefix, &block)
    m = Module.new
    m.instance_eval(&block)
    m.methods(false).each do |name|
      define_method "#{prefix}_#{name}", &m.method(name)
      module_function "#{prefix}_#{name}" unless self.is_a?(Class)
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  with_prefix :get do
    with_prefix :and do
      def foo
        puts "У меня есть мысль, и я её думаю!"
      end

      def bar
        puts "А можно я её тоже немножечко подумаю?"
      end
    end
  end
end

foo = Foo.new

foo.get_and_foo # => "У меня есть мысль, и я её думаю!"
foo.get_and_bar # => "А можно я её тоже немножечко подумаю?"
```

### Что делает этот код?

- Объявляет метод `with_prefix` в суперклассе всех классов
- Метод принимает имя префикса и блок кода
- Выполняет блок в контексте анонимной функции
- Это позволяет исполнять оператор `def` в анонимном модуле, а не в классе
- Перебирает все *методы* внутри модуля
- Создаёт методы с префиксами для каждого *метода*

Comment: Неплохо бы ещё кратко описать, как это работает. Вы сделали новый анонимный модуль, определили в нём методы переданным от пользователя блоком, затем, беря методы из `.methods(false)` методом `.method` (к-к-к-ко-о-омбо) определили их с префиксом в том скоупе, где метод `with_prefix` вызван. И стоит приложить ссылки на документацию к используемым методам рефлексии :)